# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpython.with_notebook'

Tags: module, vpython

I'm trying to install vpython on visual studio code and executing it in a jupyter nootebook, but I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpython.with_notebook'

```
from vpython import *
#from vpython import canvas,vector,sphere,cylinder,rate
from numpy import sqrt,array
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot,show

# constantes del problema

G=6.674e-11
M=1.989e30

# definimos la función de nuestro sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales

def f(r):
    x=r[0]
    y=r[1]
    vx=r[2]
    vy=r[3]
    
    r3=(x*x+y*y)**1.5

    fx=vx
    fy=vy
    fvx=-G*M*x/r3
    fvy=-G*M*y/r3
    
    return array([fx,fy,fvx,fvy],float)

# condiciones inciales

x0=4e12
y0=0
vx0=0
vy0=500

r=array([x0,y0,vx0,vy0],float)
scene=canvas(width=400,height=400,center=vector(x0/2,0,0))
scale=5e7
rs=1400
mc=10
sun=sphere(pos=vector(x0/30,0,0),radius=rs*scale,color=vector(255,250,0))
s=sphere(pos=vector(x0,y0,0),radius=50*mc*scale)
framerate=100

i=1
while i<len(xpp):       
    rate(framerate)
    s.pos=vector(xpp[i],ypp[i],0)
    i+=1
    scene=canvas(width=400,height=400,center=vector(x0/2,0,0))
    scale=5e7
    rs=1400
    mc=10
    sun=sphere(pos=vector(x0/30,0,0),radius=rs*scale,color=vector(255,250,0))
    s=sphere(pos=vector(x0,y0,0),radius=50*mc*scale)
    framerate=100
    
    i=1
    while i<len(xpp):       
        rate(framerate)
        s.pos=vector(xpp[i],ypp[i],0)
        i+=1
```

I have tried installing different versions of Jupyter Lab, Jupyter Notebook and Vpython and nothing happened. Why there is that many problems installing this package?

Thanks for reading

Comment: You should include the entire traceback where you see `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpython.with_notebook'`. In this case posting code you are trying to run beyond the `import statement` isn't much help there because I assume the examples give the same error? I assume the first import throws the error? Did you follow [here to install](https://vpython.org/presentation2018/install.html)? As to your comment, "Why there is that many problems installing this package?": it is particularly complex software unlike much of the typical Python-based code you encounter in the Jupyter ecosystem.

Comment: <continued> I would look into Web VPython discussed [here](https://vpython.org/presentation2018/noinstall.html) for easier way to use it at this time.

Comment: Which Python are you trying with? [A recent post in the VPython Google group at  Nov 28 10:47AM -0800](http://groups.google.com/group/vpython-users/t/ea88c0ec5c5c20b0) says there is no version for Python 3.11 yet. "It shouldn't work with Python 11; we don't yet have version of the vpython module for Python 11."-SOURCE: Bruce Sherwood, developer of VPython

Comment: It looks very odd to say "from vpython import *" and then import a list of objects.